# How to get the git commit from an openshift deploy?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, openshift

Our developers push a git commit to "development branch" and that will trigger openshift to deploy the new code (as a docker image).

Then QA promotes the same image by tagging it to be deployed to QA's instance for integration testing and other testing.

These all works but when QA tags the latest image in the development namespace, how can we get the original git commit which triggered this image to be created? We need this to calculate which bugs/issues were included in this image.

Or , even there's a better way without changing the deploy method (I don't want to add Jenkins build that triggers the deploy in openshift).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, not sure if there's a better way.

Run the following in the dev project,

```
$ oc describe imagestreamtag <imagestream>:<the tag I am interested in>
```

This will give me information about the git repo that this image was created on, and the git commit label. From there I can query git to find out the list of tickets included in the commit (and images).